# Threadstatic flag needed or not?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance

I am working with Threads. I am unsure if the flag `ThreadStatic` Is needed or not. In any thread anyway a can access the simple type of boolean.

When working over several threads what is enought:

```
Private _ImageToggle As Boolean
```

or

```
 <ThreadStatic()> Private _ImageToggle As Boolean
```

*** MY INTERPRETATION of Marc Gravells answer ***

If there are several instances which each are using multithreading, the "Threadstatic" flag can be a solution to use a shared value. As far as I understood rightnow for basic types it does never makes sense.

Comment: For "is it needed", we *generally* need much more detail about what the context is. Especially with threading, the "how is it used/consumed/changed?" is **incredibly** important.

Comment: Ok Marc. With other words I can ask, WHEN is it needed? In my question I am only speaking about threads and the access to the shared value. Perhaps you know a situation where this flag is important?

Comment: when you want there to be a single value *per thread* (rather than a single value overall). For example, maybe each thread represents a different connection/client. But as I mention, I'd much rather have an explicit context instance myself, and just pass that instance to each thread as needed - easier to re-use threads safely, that way.

Comment: WHOWW I could not believe that your right before reading your message... but ok, thats the most interesting answer to my question. Thanks for that *up*

Comment: Re your interpretation... well "instances" is confusing, as static != instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it isn't `static` (`Shared` in VB), `[ThreadStatic]` has no effect. No; it does not need this.

When applied to a static field, `[ThreadStatic]` means that each thread is talking to a different value (essentially it becomes thread-local-storage). This is double-edged, as any async-based (including ASP.NET and WCF) code needs to be *really* careful. In general I would avoid this flag - it is better to use an instance member and pass that around (between threads) as the context.